# How to use Python to input to and get output from C++ program?

Tags: python, c++, testing, io

I'm currently trying to automate the testing of a C++ program which takes input from the terminal and outputs the result onto the terminal. For example my C++ file would do something like below:

```
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    int a, b;
    std::cin >> a >> b;
    std::cout << a + b;
}
```

And my Python file used for testing would be like:

```
as = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
bs = [2, 3, 1, 4, 5]
results = []

for i in range(5):
    # input a[i] and b[i] into the C++ program
    # append answer from C++ program into results
```

Although it is possible to input and output from C++ through file I/O, I'd rather leave the C++ program untouched.

What can I do instead of the commented out lines in the Python program?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use [`subprocess.Popen`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#popen-constructor). Sample code:

```cpp
#include <iostream>

int sum(int a, int b) {
    return a + b;
}


int main ()
{
    int a, b;

    std::cin >> a >> b;
    std::cout << sum(a, b) << std::endl;
    
}
```

```py
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE

program_path = "/home/user/sum_prog"

p = Popen([program_path], stdout=PIPE, stdin=PIPE)
p.stdin.write(b"1\n")
p.stdin.write(b"2\n")
p.stdin.flush()

result = p.stdout.readline().strip()
assert result == b"3"
```

Answer (score 2):

```
python_program.py | cpp_program
```

On the command line will feed the standard output of `python_program.py` into the standard input of `cpp_program`.

This works for all executables, no matter what programming language they are written in.

Comment: I think the question is not how to feed the output from the python script to the cpp application. It seems that george is trying to feed values into the cpp application and check for the expected output.

Answer (score 0):

You can comunicate it by .txt
Write txt with your matrix and read it on Python, 2 programms cant use same memory.

Else use Cython and code your C++ on Python
https://github.com/cythonbook/examples/tree/master/07-wrapping-c/01-wrapping-c-functions-mt-random

Answer (score 0):

You will need to use pythons `subprocess` module (https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html) to start your compiled C++ application and send in your variables and read the output of the subprocess using `Popen.communicate()` (https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.Popen.communicate).

Example code might look like:

```
import subprocess
p = subprocess.Popen(["cpp_app", stdin=subprocess.PIPE,stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
out, _ = p.communicate(b"1 2")
print(out, err)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use supproccess for getting data from called program, example for whois:

```
import subprocess
proc = subprocess.Popen(['whois', 'google.com'], stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
data = proc.communicate()[0]
print( data )
```